# Akka streams - throw away a message

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a flow that looks like this:

```
case class T1 extends A 
case class T2 extends A
case class T3 extends A

val proc: Flow[A, B, Unit] =   Flow[A] .map {
         case x: T1 => B()
         case x: T2 => B()
         case x: T3 => 
               save_message(x)
               // now throw away the message
 }
 .transform(() => lastStage)

 val lastStage = ...
 def save_message(msg: A): Unit = ...
```

So in this code, I receive a message of base type A, if it's of derived type T1 or T2. However if it's of type T3, I just want to throw it away and not pass it to the lastStage, just go on to the next message. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `collect` instead of `map`:

```
case class T1 extends A 
case class T2 extends A
case class T3 extends A

val proc: Flow[A, B, Unit] =   Flow[A].collect {
         case x: T1 => B()
         case x: T2 => B()
 }
 .transform(() => lastStage)

 val lastStage = ...
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor. That works, except that in one of my cases I need to do some processing on the message coming into the flow (store it), but I don't need to send it to the lastStage. I modified the question slightly to clarify this case. collect chokes on this corner case.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to create a broadcast where you ignore T1s and T2s in one branch and send them to a Sink which persists T3s and on the other branch you drop T3s.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up modifying my approach a little (used a combination of Either and Option to create additional states), so I can use filterNot to remove the unwanted messages. May not be sustainable in more complex code, but works for my simple needs. Hopefully there will be a simpler way to do this in the future and I will update then. For now, I will accept your answer since it may solve other people's issues. Thanks!